# spring eclipselink static weaving was not enabled or did not occur

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

Project uses:

- spring boot 2.1.1
- oracle 12 database
- eclipselink 2.6.5
- maven 3.6.0

in this project we are using a provided jar with the entities and we created the configuration withouth persistence.xml. The project is created as a war to be deployed in weblogic 12c server but we are testing with springboot inbuilt tomcat server. And ocasionaly on a test server with Weblogic.

When we launch the application in either container we get a lot of EL warnings like the following one:

```
[EL Warning]: metadata: 2019-02-28 17:10:14.684--ServerSession(1764986459)--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [readonlyUserInformation] for the entity class [class com.adquira.mkp.persistence.entities.auditory.AuditoryEvent] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
```

after searching and looking everywhere how to solve this the only similar question we found was [this question about static weaving not working in springboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39934587/eclipselink-static-weaving-and-spring-boot-is-not-working)

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.adus</groupId>
    <artifactId>adus-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>adus-backend</name>
    <description>Adus back-end development</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springfox-swagger.version>2.9.2</springfox-swagger.version>
        <eclipselink.version>2.6.5</eclipselink.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adquira.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>adquira-orm</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>   
        <!-- swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
            <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The class for configuration

```
package com.adus.adusbackend;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.eclipse.persistence.config.PersistenceUnitProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter;


@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.adus.adusbackend.repository.user","com.adus.adusbackend.repository.market"})
public class DatasourceConfiguration  {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
      public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
      }

    @Bean
    EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle12Platform");
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.FALSE);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);

        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaDialect(new EclipseLinkJpaDialect());

        // Instead of persistence.xml
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("des");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.adquira.mkp.persistence.entities");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.WEAVING, detectWeavingMode());
        jpaProperties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.DDL_GENERATION, "none");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        entityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private String detectWeavingMode() {
        return InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.isInstrumentationAvailable() ? "true" : "static";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two challenges.

Firstly: to have static weaving to happen at all and entities enhanced you need a properly configured maven plugin to do that. You need to add weaver plugin to your plugin section. Example from [Eclipselink Wiki-page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving):

```
<plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>de.empulse.eclipselink</groupId>
        <artifactId>staticweave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>weave</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <persistenceXMLLocation>
                        META-INF/persistence.xml</persistenceXMLLocation>
                    <logLevel>FINE</logLevel>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
                <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    ...
</plugins>
```

Secondly: you need to make plugin aware the classes in external jar. There were quite few articles about that and I am not sure if it is even possible (easily). The wiki page mentions only about *sources to weave* which can be in a jar but does not directly say if it is possible also for compiled classes.

For this reason I have always made my entity library jars readily enhanced when compiled from source. But anyway there are some related posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41564689/6413377).

Comment: My problem so to speak, is that i don't have an persistence.xml, everything is anotation based and because this is a war file i can't reference external entities in a jar because they live in different parts of the target

Comment: @xerido Yes. But actually for weaving you can add a `persistence.xml` file only for that, having just the needed information for weaver. I remember doing that when generated jars having only enhanced entities.  But for ready jars having entiteis do not know if it is possible still.

Comment: In the end talking with the client about the problems and solutions we got an preweaved with included persistence jar. anyways part of your solution is still correct ( we made it possible to make some clases weaved)